# Bash files open in vim instead of running in terminal

Tags: bash, scripts, vim

I'm a newbie on Ubuntu trying to learn how to write and use scripts. When I make an executable file (`chmod +x`, `chmod 755`) and try to run it the file simply opens in vim instead of running...

[image: image of an opened file]

Comment: How do yo try to run the script? Double clicking on it in the file manager?

Answer (score 3):

Move your mouse cursor to the top of your screen and click on the `Edit` tab. Then select `Preferences`.
[image: Nautilus Edit Menu]

Then select the `Behaviour`-tab. Mark on `Ask each time`.
[image: File Preferences Dialog]

Then you will get a dialog box to execute as you want like below image.
[image: Dialog Box with multiple choices for shell script (Execute, edit, etc..)]